# Finding all four-digit perfect squares of the form $XXYY$

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Can you find a four digit number of the form $XXYY$ using only mathematical tools (without a computer) where the first two digits are same ($XX$) and the last two digits are same ($YY$), and the number $XXYY$ is a perfect square. How many such numbers can exist (again without using a computer) ?
>
> $XXYY = (AB)^2$

Comment: What do you think? Show what you have tried.

Comment: The only such example is $88^2=7744$.

Comment: I have tried on pen and paper. And this solution is possible even without a calculator. I am more interested to see the working.

Comment: 7744 is the only example thats correct. This number was the Helpline VOIP Number in a Software MNC.May be it still is.

Comment: @PeterForeman was quite fast with the solution. But the working is much more interesting.

Comment: @AbhraGupta: *"7744 is the only example thats correct."* ... If you know the answer to your question, you should say so, so that people don't waste time thinking you need help.

Comment: Got it @Blue, I joined a few minutes back. Will take some time to get the flow of things. How things work around here.

Comment: @DavidK if it is of the form XXYY then it must be divisible by 11. And if its a perfect square, it should be divisibleby 121 as 11 is a prime. There exists only few perfects quares from 16 to 81 which compliments for 121. and the only one is 64.Hence 121x64=7744 which is 88^2

Comment: Those are the details I meant by "show what you have tried." The standard practice is to include all of that in the question when you ask it. And also to still have some kind of question at the end: "Is this correct?" or "What other ways could it be done?"

Comment: @AbhraGupta: Welcome! The primary thing is to remember and respect that people spend their valuable free time here to *help* people. The more you can say in a question about what kind of assistance you do (and don't) need, the better. (That's why people ask "What have you tried?") Importantly, puzzles to which you know the answer aren't really appropriate here —there's [Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) for that— unless you are seeking an explanation of, or alternatives to, a known solution. (In such cases, you should include the solution you know as part of the question itself.)

Comment: I am sorry I assumed it would be fun to share an interesting problem. I didn't know thisforum is only for problems that are not solvable by the inquirer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$XXYY$ is divisible by $11$, so $AB$ must also be. So $\frac{XXYY}{11}=X0Y$ is also divisible by $11$. That means that X and $Y$ must add up to $11$. So $\frac{X0Y}{11}=\frac{Y+(11-Y)\cdot100}{11}=100-9Y$ must be a perfect square. Now you can easily go through the digits for $Y$ and check that only $Y=4$ works.

Comment: Alternatively, since $11$ is a factor and it is a square, $121$ must be a factor. So $XXYY = 121 n^2$, where $n$ is a (small) positive integer.